# Make a static build with a program using sqlite

Tags: c, shared-libraries

**Context:** I'm doing this as an experiment to understand how static vs dynamic linking works, please avoid saying it is stupid or whatever. It has interests and I can't find much about by googling.

TL;DR: go to "The problem" point.

**First step:** the program. I tried this little program using sqlite, it is stupid, but enough to illustrate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!\n");
   printf("%s\n", sqlite3_libversion()); 

   return 0;
}
```

**Building:** I have the following Makefile

```
build:
    gcc -o test main.c -lsqlite3
```

**Static build:** this is the whole point here. I tried this Makefile.

```
build.o:
    gcc -c main.c

build.static: build.o
    gcc main.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a -o static-test
```

Why?

1. I use the binary libsqlite3.a to replace libsqlite (obviously)
2. After trying to compile, I had some issues with pthread, so I added pthread.a binary

**The problem:** I still get issues... But I now have issues asking for `dlopen` (and so on). Isn't this supposed to be included by default? Also, it is used to... Include new library dynamically, how can I end this dependency hell?

```
$ make build.static                   
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a -o static-test
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o) : dans la fonction « fts5Bm25Function » :
(.text+0x2c914) : référence indéfinie vers « log »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o) : dans la fonction « unixDlError » :
(.text+0x345e3) : référence indéfinie vers « dlerror »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o) : dans la fonction « unixDlClose » :
(.text+0x8358) : référence indéfinie vers « dlclose »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o) : dans la fonction « unixDlSym » :
(.text+0x836b) : référence indéfinie vers « dlsym »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(sqlite3.o) : dans la fonction « unixDlOpen » :
(.text+0x837d) : référence indéfinie vers « dlopen »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(pthread_create.o) : dans la fonction « allocate_stack » :
/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/allocatestack.c:525 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_stack_flags »
/usr/bin/ld : /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/allocatestack.c:647 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_stack_flags »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(elision-lock.o) : dans la fonction « do_set_elision_enable » :
/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/elision-conf.c:66 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_x86_cpu_features »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o) : dans la fonction « __pthread_initialize_minimal_internal » :
/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/nptl-init.c:335 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_pagesize »
/usr/bin/ld : /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/nptl-init.c:344 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_pagesize »
/usr/bin/ld : /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/nptl-init.c:360 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_init_static_tls »
/usr/bin/ld : /build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/nptl-init.c:362 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_wait_lookup_done »
/usr/bin/ld : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(nptl-init.o) : dans la fonction « __pthread_get_minstack » :
/build/glibc-ZN95T4/glibc-2.31/nptl/nptl-init.c:393 : référence indéfinie vers « _dl_pagesize »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8 : build.static] Erreur 1
```

Comment: If you have "issues", then please tell them to us. For example, if you have build errors then please copy-paste them (in full and complete, and as text) into the question itself.

Comment: You didn't include the header for dlopen. So whats your 'issues'?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry I forgot to include the output. Fixed! Devolus, you can see that my code doesn't use dlopen!

Comment: So this sounds like a case of you reaching into the guts of something you don't understand. It sounds like `libsqlite` contains more than just `libsqlite3.a`. In other words, it contains whatever else `libsqlite3.a` is dependent on and probably whatever those dependencies require as well.  Take a look at how `libsqlite` is built. There's probably a way to build a static version of it, that you can use.

Comment: And you probably need to read this: https://sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/README.md

Comment: I don't understand. It would be great if libsqlite embbed everything it uses, also it's already a binary isn't it? What do you mean?

Comment: Static libraries are nothing more than collections of object files, and linking with such a library is like linking with the actual object files themselves. Because of this, the dependencies of the library is not included in the library, and you must link with them yourself.

Comment: I understand that but I don't get how to know what are the dependencies.

Comment: Forgot to add `-ldl` to the end of the command. (No, it is not supposed to happen automagically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ℹ️ You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094108/2263684 which is really instructive on the topic.

The first solution is to use ldd to see what are the dependencies. Then you need to add them to the compile command like it they are going to be link (they are not going to). This may have issues because the order matters. Here is what was the solution for my case:

```
gcc -o test main.c libsqlite3.a -lm -ldl -lpthread -static
```

Another solution probably more reliable is to use `pkg-config`, it gives the libraries to link and their order to include (in my case) sqlite:

```
# Gives the name of the package
pkg-config --list-all | grep sqlite
# Give dependencies... In the right order!
pkg-config --static --libs sqlite3
```

Once you have dependencies, just re-compose the build method with them.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic libraries contain a list of dependencies to other dynamic libraries. If the dynamic library is loaded, the system will automatically try to locate and also load the dependencies of it.

E.g. if you link against `libA` and `libA` depends on `libB`, your main executable doesn't have to link against `libB` because `libB` will automatically be loaded when `libA` is loaded.

No such thing exists for static libraries. Static libraries are just archives of object files (think of multiple `.o` files wrappend into a single `.tar` file). Object files have no list of dependencies. When you link object files to a dynamic library or executable binary, you tell the linker which other libraries are required and from that arguments, the list of dependencies is created.

E.g.

```
ld -shared -o xyz -l abc -l efg *.o
```

This call instructs `ld` to create a dynamic library named `xyz` and link it against the libraries `abc` and `efg`. And in case those two are dynamic libraries, they are added to the dependency list of `xyz`. Thus whoever loads `xyz` must then also load `abc` and `efg`.

However, object files have not been linked yet. They are the results of compiled source code files and to compile source code files, you don't have to even specify any libraries. Thus object files have no dependencies and archives of object files have neither. You need to ensure that you satisfy all decencies when linking against them.

As static libraries have no dependency list, there is no simple way to find out on which other libraries they depend. If that isn't documented anywhere, you can only look which symbols are missing when you try to link against them and then locate the libraries offering those symbols and link against those as well.

In case you also have a dynamic library version of your static one, you are lucky as then you can just check which dependencies the dynamic library has.

```
ldd someLibrary

objdump -p someLibrary | grep NEEDED

readelf -d someLibrary | grep NEEDED
```

All three commands list the direct dependencies, `ldd` also lists the indirect one (dependencies of the dependencies) when called with `--verbose`, in case of the others you have ti traverse the entire dependency chain yourself. Pick whichever works on your system or can be installed in case it is missing.

For a real static binary, you need to have static versions of all direct and indirect dependencies and link against all of them.

Fun fact:
Now that you know that static libraries are just archives of object files, it's quite obvious where the file extension `.a` comes from or why the tool to create them is named `ar`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is now limpid in my mind. I understand I need to link all ".a" file that sqlite requires (and also dependencies of its dependencies). How can I know what I should add? I tried to compile with `libsqlite3.a`, `libpthread.a`, `libm.a` and `libdl.a`... But all I get is warnings (because dlopen is used) and failures to compile.

Comment: @Nek Please update your question to show the new compile call which includes all those libraries (as the one in the question does not) and show the new compiler output this call produces. Please don't delete what you currently have in the question, so people can understand where you are coming from and where you currently are. Rather add your update to the end of it. I added a hint to my question how to check dependencies of dynamic libraries. If you build a dynamic libsqlite, you can check its dependencies, the static one should have the same dependencies.

Comment: thank you, you helped a lot but I didn't succeed directly. I will post my solution.